# Difficulty removing website from AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nameserver, dns-zone, 504

Designing a website for a client and taking over from previous guy who set it all up in AWS. I’m not familiar and the learning curve is steep. The last few days I’m getting a 504 gateway problem and the website is broken.

So, bought new traditional hosting today. Want to extract from AWS without breaking their other assets. Usually I can just change the A records to the new IP and it will redirect after an hour, but AWS is not letting go. It just gave me a site not found error.

Here is the current setup as I understand it:

1. Route 53: Hosted zone in AWS, not registered domain
2. current ‘A’ record is an alias, pointing to a load balancer in EC2
3. Has an amazon-provided SSL cert
4. LB listener has a target group with redirect rules

Never heard of any of this before last week, except ‘A’ records. All I want now is to know how to safely repoint the nameservers and start using the new hosting. The listeners etc are in use by other sites so I have to be careful not to interfere with them.

edit2: deleted reference to actual website and IP address

Answer (score 0):

I have briefly looked at it...

1. The website at https://rawgyms.com seems to work ok. Not failing with 504 errors.
2. The website at http://195.7.226.157 doesn't seem to be ready.

I would start by bringing the website up at the new address and then yes, simply change the A record to the new IP. The current one is probably an "ALIAS" since it points to a load balancer. For your new one simply set the A (non-ALIAS) record to 195.7.226.157. Make sure the TTL is set to a low value (e.g. 300 sec = 5 mins) in case you'll need to revert it.

---

On the other hand since you already have the website running on AWS I would **spend some time learning the AWS platform**. Cloud platforms and AWS in particular are becoming more and more popular and if you're working in this industry sooner or later you will need to be across it. It's now a mainstream, not some obscure technology. Invest your time in learning it :)

Here on ServerFault we can often help with any specific problems.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried changing the A records but it didn’t work - is that because the new site isn’t ready? It’s been 12 hours now how long should it take to come live? It usually works straight away for me.

Comment: @PaulMurphy It still resolves to Amazon. Update your question with a screenshot of the Route53 zone, incl the SOA and NS records, I’ll have a look.

Comment: Ok I have done that

Comment: @PaulMurphy i don’t see any updates to the question

Comment: Hi, can you see the attached photo now?

Comment: I can. The first line still says `rawgyms.com A ALIAS dualstsck....` - that’s the load balancer. I thought you have changed that to `rawgyms.com A 195.7.226.157`? Looks like you didn’t.

Comment: I did it as a test, for 24 hours, but I the new site isn’t ready for launch yet. It’s just that when I did the test i expected it to show me the IP page (currently says ‘don’t let this space go to waste”), but instead it just said this page could not be loaded.

Comment: When you’re ready with the new site create `www2.rawgyms.com` as A record for 195.7.226.157 and verify that it works. Once it does do the same for `rawgyms.com` and `www.rawgyms.com`. If it doesn’t work *then* ask here.

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand. I would turn off alias, and enter  195.7.226.157 instead. Where would I enter www2.rawgyms.com ?

Comment: Absolutely. If you want to change it you have to delete the alias record first. Then click the **Create Record Set** button at the top and fill in the details in the right hand side panel.

Comment: Brill. Would it be good practise to delete the load balancer, target group etc when they are redundant?

Comment: Yes, once it all works on the new IP. Not before just in case you need to roll back. There may be a fair bit of things to delete though but that’s a topic for another question.